# Number of real roots of the equation $2\cos(x) =(2^x+2^{-x})/2$

Tags: transcendental-equations, elementary-functions

> What's the number of real roots of the equation $2\cos(x) =(2^x+2^{-x})/2$?

If any questions ask about real root what is the main thing to check first, and most important?

Any particular way to handle these type of questions?

Comment: "this type of questions" is not so clear.

Comment: You can rewrite $2^x$ as $e^{x\ln 2}$ so really you want to solve $2\cos x = \cosh (x\ln 2)$.

Answer (score 1):

You get the existence of two solution by mean value theorem, we have
$$2\cos(0)-\frac{2^0 +2^{-0}}{2}=2-1=1>0$$
but for $|x|$ large enough it is clear that 
$$2\cos(x)-\frac{2^x +2^{-x}}{2}<0$$
because $2^{|x|}$ goes to infinity. The functions are continous, so we get a positive and a negative real solution.

You can also show that there are only two solutions because $\frac{2^x +2^{-x}}{2}$ is monotonous on $(0,\infty)$ and for $x=2$ it's already greater than $2=\max_x 2\cos(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to consider the interval $(0,\infty)$, as if $x$ is a solution, also $-x$ is.

The function $x\mapsto (2^x-2^{-x})/2$ is increasing and convex, by examining its derivatives.

There is no solution with $x>\pi/2$, because

- for $\pi/2<x<\pi$ we have $2\cos x<0$ and $(2^x-2^{-x})/2>0$
- for $x\ge\pi$, $2\cos x\le2$, whereas $(2^x-2^{-x})/2>(2^3-2^{-3})/2>4$.

So we can restrict the search to the interval $[0,\pi/2]$, where the function $x\mapsto 2\cos x$ is concave and decreasing.

Thus if a solution exists it is unique.

Since $2\cos0=2$ and $(2^0+2^{-0})/2=1$, whereas $(2^{\pi/2}+2^{-\pi/2})/2>0=2\cos(\pi/2)$, a solution exists.

Comment: If we are considering the interval $(0,\infty)$, how do we conclude that $x \mapsto 2 \cos x$ is decreasing?  (Sure, on the interval $[0,\pi]$ and subintervals, but this isn't the interval you said...)

Comment: @EricTowers Yes, I said it quite badly. I was thinking to the interval $[0,\pi/2]$, where the statement is true; for $x>\pi/2$ no solution exists.

Answer (score 0):

i doubt if this has a closed form solution; numerical solution is $\pm 0.9206433.$

Comment: OP is not looking for the solutions, but the number of solutions (also, I think your approximation is a bit off, I got around $0.91$).

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD, you are right. i accidentally solved $2cos x =(e^x + e^{-x})/2.$